# How do you use ColabTurtle?

Tags: google-colaboratory, turtle-graphics

Although I know I can install ColabTurtle to use Turtle on a Colab Notebook, I cannot figure out how. 
Could someone please give me an example on how to run Turtle codes on Colab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an [example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Gu4v20Gf7s6vXvzRZQhni9bMRrSkp_tf).

First, you need to install it.

```
!pip install ColabTurtle
```

Then import all functions and init it.

```
from ColabTurtle.Turtle import *
initializeTurtle()
```

Then call normal turtle commands, e.g.

```
forward(100)
right(90)
forward(100)
right(90)
forward(100)
```

You can see all supported commands in [the code](https://github.com/tolgaatam/ColabTurtle/blob/master/ColabTurtle/Turtle.py).